# Generic method to filter a list object

Tags: c#, generics, filter

I am trying to create a generic method that takes three parameters.
1) List collection
2) String PropertyName
3) String FilterString

The idea is we pass a collection of Objects, the name of the property of the object 
and a Filter Criteria and it returns back a list of Objects where the property contains
the FilterString.

Also, the PropertyName is optional so if its not supplied I would like to return
all objects that contain the FilterString in any property.

Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

I am trying to have a method signature like this:
public static List FilterList(List collection, String FilterString, String Property = "")

This way I can call this method from anywhere and pass it any List and it would return me a filtered list.

Comment: You need reflection and/or expression trees.

Comment: You'll have to use some reflection. Make an attempt and come back when you have a concrete issue!

Comment: Why not just use Linq?

Comment: Forget string based stuff, use LINQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do what you want using LINQ, as such,

```
var collection = ...
var filteredCollection = 
    collection.Where(item => item.Property == "something").ToList();
```

Otherwise, you could try Reflection,

```
public List<T> Filter<T>(
    List<T> collection, 
    string property, 
    string filterValue)
{
    var filteredCollection = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
         // To check multiple properties use,
         // item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)

         var propertyInfo = 
             item.GetType()
                 .GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
         if (propertyInfo == null)
             throw new NotSupportedException("property given does not exists");             

         var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
         if (propertyValue == filterValue)
             filteredCollection.Add(item);       
    }

    return filteredCollection;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that changes to the name of the property or misspellings result in a runtime error, rather than a compilation error as would be using an actual property expression where the name is hard-typed.

Also, do note that based on the binding flags, this will work only on `public`, `non-static` properties. You can modify such behavior by passing different [flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I make this a method that can accept any List so instead of List<SomeObject> the method would look like this;
 public static List<T> FilterList<T>(List<T> collection, String FilterString, String Property = "")

Comment: You can just literally change `SomeObject` to `T`, and make the method generic. I've made the chance to give you a clue.

Comment: @user3067743 it is possible with help of Dynamic LINQ, I've provided an answer also.

Comment: Is this a right way to allow only `string` properties? `if (propertyInfo == null || propertyInfo.PropertyType != typeof(string)) throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported property.");`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of reflection and dynamic expressions for this. I've put together a sample that might look a bit long at the first look. However, it matches your requirements and addresses these by

- Using reflection to find the properties that are of type string and match the property name - if provided.
- Creating an expression that calls string.Contains on all properties that have been identified. If several properties have been identified, the calls to string.Contains are combined by Or-expressions. This filter expression is compiled and handed to the Where extension method as a parameter. The provided list is filtered using the expression.

Follow this [link](http://ideone.com/XE7rm7) to run the sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Test
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string propName, string value)
    {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propName))
            props = new PropertyInfo[] { typeof(T).GetProperty(propName) };
        else
            props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        props = props.Where(x => x != null && x.PropertyType == typeof(string));
        Expression lastExpr = null;
        ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        ConstantExpression valueExpr = Expression.Constant(value);
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            var propExpr = GetPropertyExpression(prop, paramExpr, valueExpr);
            if (lastExpr == null)
                lastExpr = propExpr;
            else
                lastExpr = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Or, lastExpr, propExpr);
        }
        if (lastExpr == null)
            return new T[] {};
        var filterExpr = Expression.Lambda(lastExpr, paramExpr);
        return items.Where<T>((Func<T, bool>) filterExpr.Compile());
    }

    private static Expression GetPropertyExpression(PropertyInfo prop, ParameterExpression paramExpr, ConstantExpression valueExpr)
    {
        var memberAcc = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExpr, prop);
        var containsMember = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
        return Expression.Call(memberAcc, containsMember, valueExpr);
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public string SomeProp { get; set; }
        public string SomeOtherProp { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new TestClass[] {
            new TestClass() { SomeProp = "AAA", SomeOtherProp = "BBB" }, 
            new TestClass() { SomeProp = "BBB", SomeOtherProp = "CCC" }, 
            new TestClass() { SomeProp = "CCC", SomeOtherProp = "AAA" }, 
        };
        var result = SelectItems(data, "", "A");
        foreach(var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine(item.SomeProp);
    }
}
```

In contrast to a completely reflection based approach, this one assembles the filter expression only once and compiles it, so that I'd expect a (small) performance improvement.

Comment: I must say, that is very concise and self explanatory. Thank you. Due to my noob rank, I cant mark this as helpful, but I found it useful and I am sure many other will in the future as well. Thanks man...

Comment: wow, this is amazing, I didn't know c# could actually do this. Amazing coding thank you!

Comment: @harris you're welcome. Glad that it helped :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), for example, given `SomeClass`:

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public int SomeField { get; set; }
}
List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>() { new SomeClass() { SomeField = 2 } };
```

and then:

```
var temp = list.AsQueryable().Where("SomeField == 1").Select("it");
var result= temp .Cast<SomeClass>().ToList();
```

So your function would be even simpler, with property name and filter merged into one parameter:

```
public List<T> Filter<T>(List<T> list, string filter)
{
    var temp = list.AsQueryable().Where(filter).Select("it");
    return temp.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

and you can provide different filters, like for example `"SomeField > 4 && SomeField < 10"` etc.

Comment: I tried your solution too and it works as advertised. Dont see any difference in performance. Thanks Konrad.

Answer (score 2):

When using Markus solution it'll only work when all String properties are not null.
To ensure you could do this:

```
class TestClass
{
    private string _someProp { get; set; }
    public string SomeProp { 
        get
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_someProp)
            {
                _someProp = "";
            }
            return _someProp;
        }
        set
        {
            _someProp = value;
        }
    }
    private string _someOtherProp { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProp { 
        get
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_someOtherProp)
            {
                _someOtherProp = "";
            }
            return _someOtherProp;
        }
        set
        {
            _someOtherProp = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Since my rep is less then 50 I cannot comment;)