# sorting, filtering, and paging with entity framework core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a tabular grid of data and will have every column header sortable (both ascending and descending) as well as filterable by a textbox underneath the column name.

I've done some digging to find out the best approach to generating my LINQ queries for entity framework and best I found was this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.0

That just uses a big switch / case (for ordering only...doesn't even consider multiple filtering options beyond one).  Surely there's got to be a better, more concise approach than this?

I'm half tempted to just use my old sproc and call the sproc with EF if this is really the path I'll have to go down.

Ideally, I'd want something like this:

```
    return myContext.Where(x => 
x.%thisisadynamicfield%.Contains("%somefiltervalue%" && 
x.%anotherdynamicfield%.Contains("%someothervalue%" && ...)
.OrderBy(x => x.%someorderybydynamicfield%)
```

I'm ok using a conditional to determine ordering ascending or descending, but I'd really like to compact everything else as much as possible and that MS article I linked above looks like code vomit and it would only cover part of my needs.

EDIT: as is almost always the case, as soon as I post here and try one more searching effort, I find what I'm looking for.  I just found this: https://github.com/harshwPro/EntityFrameworkPaginate which looks very promising.  I will report back here if that solves my issue.

EDIT 2: well the github project I referenced in my first edit is certainly a cleaner solution than the MS article I posted originally but it still leaves me with writing a huge conditional to generate my filters by property.  Using that solution, I'd have to write something like this:
`dataPagingModel.Filters.Add(true, x => x.MyCoolProperty.Contains("blah"));` but would have to conditionally add new filters based on my angular presentation layer's posted parameters - switch / case, or some huge if / else block.  What I'd ideally like is a way to just loop over all of the posted filters list and dynamically add those filters in a loop.  So I guess my question now boils down to, is there a way to access properties of an object dynamically (generically) in a lambda expression?

EDIT 3: I think this SO post has the answers I need: [Generic method to filter a list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386634/generic-method-to-filter-a-list-object)

Comment: you should check Gridify library
https://github.com/alirezanet/gridify